# More than one data container in the same report in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I would like to create an invoice report and would like to place the client information (tsql query from another dataset) that repeats over multiple pages. The body of the report pulls information from a table. How can I accomplish this? Is placing a header/ subreport an option? What other options do I have.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try, group data in table and make break page on each instance of group.
That will put group data on each page.